# My arm ik does not adjust to the movements

Tags: rigging

I was creating a Minecraft rig for the first time, I had some bugs but I have fixed them, this is the most disgusting bug that I found, I don't know much about rigging but I have not found the solution to the problem and that is why I came to ask for help.

What happens is that when the **arm** is returned to the **original pose**, the **rotation is not adjuste**d, in addition to that the arm when I give it movements it moves more than what I mark. And for it to stay in the **original rotation** I have to **spam** the **Alt + R** key and it is too annoying ..

The truth is that I had a good time investigating and nothing :(

***I attach a gif so you can see what happens***.

[image]

2 cycles dependency

[image]

Comment: Check first for any dependency cycles, which can be identified most easily by looking at a console window (main window menu -> toggle system console).

Comment: @Nathan I have 2 dependencies, I attach another image in the post so you can see, I don't understand how that dependencies work, could you help me with the problem that the console gives me?

Comment: Trace it through, and if you can't figure something out, see if you can figure it out if you ignore it.  Eje depends on PoleFixMid, which depends on PoleFixTop, which depends on Eje.  Trace your constraints through and think about them-- each thing needs to depend on the previous/next in a hierarchy, not a loop.

Comment: @Nathan The eje you say is the axis, and the polefixtop-mid-bot are bones that fit the mesh as you move it using (x) transform, and help the axis to be placed in the position to be rotated with the controller. And I do not understand why the polefixtop depends on the eje since it has nothing attached.

Comment: @Nathan I already managed to solve it !!! Thank you very much, I changed the polefix connections and it was fixed! I appreciate it, have a good afternoon!